# Someone could leave a comment in other peoples' post with 9 reputation points

Tags: support

I don't understand why this is happening, and I've checked [Help Center > Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) again. I see that the rule is still not changed. A user still needs at least 50 reputation points to leave comment on other peoples' posts.

Here is a screenshot for what's happening:

[image: 1]

Post: [Parent & child .click() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368938/parent-child-click-method)

@sonal has 9 reputation now. How can he/she leave a comment on this post (he/she is not the OP)?

---

> Maybe he/she had 50+ rep and he/she invested it in a bounty?

[sonal.paghdal's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7549065/sonal-paghdal)

I've checked in the profile, and I see this in **Top Questions**

> This user has not asked any questions.

Comment: What do we call this? A Front End injection?

Comment: Maybe he had 50+ rep and he invested it in bounty?

Comment: The user most likely posted an answer which was [automatically converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/258777).